# Page control and Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know if it's possible to add in the same view a page control and a navigation controller, and if so if there are somebody who can point me into the right direction?

Really what I need is a table view to show my data, with a navigation controller and a page control that allow you to go to the next table view where there are more data related to the first table.

I have been trying to do it with pageControl from apple developer, but with no success. Here is the link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

And I've been trying with PanelTableView https://github.com/honcheng/PanelTableView, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I made PanelTableView. What is it that you can get to work?

If you want the next table view to show more data related to the first table view, sounds like PanelTableView is not suitable for you. I think you just want to display more info when you click on a row? Isn't the drilldown sample by Apple suitable for what you want?

Maybe you can make your question clearer if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Hi Honcheng,

Really what I need is a table view, with a page control which allow me to swipe between two different tables views, and I would like to specify a different section title for each TableView, but I don't know how to do it, or which methods of PanelTableView I need to override to change the section title in each TableView.

The drillDown sample is not suitable for me, cause I want two table views and page control.

Thanks for your reply.

Chipironbombita

Comment: The latest code allows you to set different section title. You can check it out in github. It's something like panelView:sectionTitleAtPage:section:

Comment: Have u looked at the sample code? So what you want is to add in a UIPageControl?

Comment: Hello Honcheng. Yes I have looked at sample code and I have realized that you have implemented the modification I suggested you about the section titles. Great! Thank you so much! Now my tables views are working with different titles in each section. But I have implemented a new method to customize the section title, maybe you want to add to PanelTableView. I can send you my code if you are interested into. Thanks again